# Embedded iframe in pdf to generate report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-redux, powerbi-embedded

I am making a fitness portal on which I am showing multiple health dashboards which are embedded using iframes from external service that I am using , I want to generate a pdf report by inserting all the iframes in the pdf file and download it.

Answer (score 2):

PDF files are not HTML files. They have no concept of iframes. But you can use a Flash component and embed it in the PDF.